# Filter values based on custom attribute in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, linq

I have two tables DefaultAttributes and CustomAttributes.

```
DefaultAttributeTable: 
1. Id
2. Product
4. Description

CustomAtrributeTable:
1. Id
2. DefaultAttributeMappingId(FK from DefaultAttributeTable)
3. CustomAtrributeName
4. CustomeAttributeValue
```

**Entries made by user**:

1. user update the values Product -> Vegetables, Description -> House Hold Item, IsOrganic(Custom Attribute created) -> True and IsDisposable(Custom Attribute created) -> True
2. user update the values Product -> Fruits, Description -> House Hold Item, IsOrganic(Custom Attribute created) -> True and IsDisposable(Custom Attribute created) -> True
3. user update the values Product -> Plastic, Description -> House Hold Item, IsOrganic(Custom Attribute created) -> False and and IsDisposable(Custom Attribute created) -> False

Then the values will be updated in the table will

DeafaultAtrributeTable:

[image]

CustomAttributeTable:
[image]

I want to combine the two tables and select the Id, product, IsOrganic, IsDisposable and filter the values based on the isorganic column. Also the custom attribute column name should be taken form the CustomAtrributeTable.  Please suggest to me how to achieve it in SQL and Linq Query. The filtered value should be

[image]

Comment: @added an answer, you might want to check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this in SQL

```
select DA.Id, DA.Product, CA.CustomeAttributeValue as IsOrganic  
from DeafaultAtrributeTable as DA inner join CustomAttributeTable as CA
on DA.Id = CA.DefaultAttributeMappingId
```

In LINQ

```
var query =
   from DA in DeafaultAtrributeTable 
   join CA in CustomAttributeTable  on DA.ID equals CA.DefaultAttributeMappingId
   where CA.CustomeAttributeValue == true
   select new { Id = DA.Id, Product = DA.Product, IsOrganic = CA.CustomeAttributeValue };
```

or LINQ extension method is

```
  var query = DeafaultAtrributeTable     // your starting point - table in the "from" statement
      .Join(CustomAttributeTable  , // the source table of the inner join
         DA => DA.ID,        // Select the primary key (the first part of the "on" clause in an sql "join" statement)
         CA => CA.DefaultAttributeMappingId,   // Select the foreign key (the second part of the "on" clause)
        (DA, CA) => new { Id = DA.Id, Product = DA.Product, IsOrganic = 
     CA.CustomeAttributeValue }) // selection 
    .Where(RES => RES.CA.CustomeAttributeValue == true);    // where statement
```

Comment: Sorry i was not clear on my requirement previously. Please check my updated query

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class Filtered
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public bool? IsOrganic { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDisposable { get; set; }
}

var result = defaultAttributeTable.Join(customAtrributeTable, DAT => DAT.Id, CAT => CAT.DefaultAttributeTableId, (DAT, CAT) => 
            new Filtered 
            {
//your join with null values for opposing isdisposable and isorganic
                ProductId = DAT.Id,
                IsDisposable = CAT.CustomAtrributeName == "IsDisposable" ? (bool?)CAT.CustomeAttributeValue : null,
                IsOrganic = CAT.CustomAtrributeName == "IsOrganic" ? (bool?)CAT.CustomeAttributeValue : null,
                ProductName = DAT.Product
            }).GroupBy(q => q.ProductId) //group it by productid
              .Select(q =>
                   new Filtered
                   {
//this will flatten opposing isorganic and isdisposable
                       ProductId = q.Key,
                       IsDisposable = q.First(e => e.IsDisposable.HasValue).IsDisposable.Value,
                       IsOrganic = q.First(e => e.IsOrganic.HasValue).IsOrganic.Value,
                       ProductName = q.First(e => e.ProductId == q.Key).ProductName
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. If the custom attribute name is dynamic and we don't know it will change based on the user products. In that case how to get the details

Comment: @hariprasath you will use reflection, though it is a lot slower, `.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName").GetValue()` do you need an answer?

Comment: did my answer helped you in your query? if it did, please mark it as answer and/or helpful

Comment: Its helpful but i want to know how i can dynamically create the class with newly created attribute value from DB

Comment: @hariprasath will supply an answer later

Comment: @hariprasath so customattributename will have a lot of different values than isdisposable and isorganic